# get the first letter of each word in a string using c++

Tags: c++, mfc

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
String = "This Is My Sentence"
```

I am looking to get this as a result: "TIMS", which takes only first letter of every word.

I am struggling with C++.

Comment: Dont see any C++ code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/237280/1056003 This answer does most of the work for you already

Comment: The question itself is not so bad. If only you had bothered to post some of you code, you would have upvotes

Comment: use this link. develop some code and then repost if you have issues http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cout<<myString[0];
for(int i=0;i<(myString.size-1);i++)
        { if(myString[i]==" ")
          {
           cout<< myString[i+1];
          {
        }
```

I didn't checked if it compiles that way but you schould get the idea of this possible simple solution. 
It will only work with strings similar to your example. You should take a look at the [Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c) Method like others already suggested.

Comment: I dont need to check your solution to tell you that it will not work. Sorry for being brutally honest

Comment: Would you kindly tell me where my idea is wrong? Only Problem I see if the String has multiple Spaces in a row but it should work in given the example.

Comment: This will not work for the first letter itself. No need to explain further.

Comment: Thank you for that Hint I didn't thought about that. My intention was to show the questioner that you can use a string like an array since he seems like a beginner. I will edit the Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `std::string` and it's `find` function.

Answer (score 0):

Split it by spaces to an array, use a for loop to get each word and add the fist letter to a string.

[Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

[For loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm)

In the loop to get the fist value just do "string_word[0]"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/tokenizer/) - the code should look somehow like this (not tested):

```
std::string firstLetters(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string result="";
    typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;
    boost::char_separator<char> sep(" ");
    tokenizer tokens(str, sep);

    for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tokens.begin();
        tok_iter != tokens.end(); ++tok_iter)
            {
                if (tok_iter->size>0)
                {
                    result+=(*tok_iter)[0];
                }
            } 
    return result;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use [Boost String Algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) (again untested)

```
std::string firstLetters(std::string& str)
{
    std::string result="";
    std::vector<std::string> splitvec;
    boost::split( splitvec, str, boost::is_any_of(" "), boost::token_compress_on );

    //C++11:  for (std::string &s : splitvec)
    BOOST_FOREACH(std::string &s, splitvec)
    {
        if (s.size()>0)
        {
            result+=s[0];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

For completeness I should mention the [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function, but this is more C than C++ ;-)

*Jost

Comment: I love Boost, really do. But in this case I'd call overkill

Comment: @nijansen only a little bit ;-)... Yes you're right, but imagine next time a solution for multiple delimiters is needed and I don't want to see a call of the `find` function for each delimiter (also think about multiple white space characters). It is simply the more powerful approach - that's why I posted it.